# Stream design, referring to additional objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getstream-io

As I get deeper into developing our application, I'm starting to wonder if what I'm doing is correct.

We have a variety of different types of info we're sharing with our users, so the Object is the reference to the thing they're sharing (a `TextBlock` for text, a `PhotoBlock` for an image, etc).

These are being shared to a feed for a `Workshop`. So a user is subscribed to all the feeds for all the workshops they're involved with, so if someone shares a photo to a specific workshop feed, everyone in that workshop sees it.

The thing is that the timeline being shared to is also associated with an object, so I can show information from the workshop within the item's display. Originally, I associated the item in the target, but using `StreamRails::Enrich` doesn't seem to enrich the object, which makes me think that's not the way to do this.

So that brings me to the larger question: is this the right way to be doing what I'm trying to do? Should I manually enrich the object (or update the Enrich object so that it does)? Or am I thinking about this in a fundamentally flawed way?

Comment: I suggest making your last paragraph the answer to this question (PR looks good and is going to be merged soon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why it's not finding the associated target: the model for Workshop has a different primary key field. Since the workshop exists in Salesforce, the primary key is `sfid`, not `id`, and the `Enrich` class seems to be searching based on the id in `retrieve_objects`: `.where(id: ids.keys)` .. instead it should be using `Model.primary_key` to determine the field to search on. I've fixed it and submitted a pull request.